# i want to copy li elements that fetched from json

Tags: javascript, json

```
$.getJSON("leftlist.json" , function(data) {
        $.each(data.articles,function(){
        $('#ullist').before("<li id='mylic' style= color:blue class='item new"+cc+"'> "+el.name+"<div class='block'><div class='row'><button   onclick='copy()' id=btnc class='col button color-blue'>copy</button><button class='col button color-blue'>fav</button><button class='col button '><a class='a2a_dd' href='https://www.addtoany.com/share'><img src='imgs/share.png' width='171' height='16' border='0' alt='Share'/></a></button></div></li></div>");

        })
   });
```

Comment: can you elaborate the question some more like what exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: He wants to build a `list` from `JSON` data.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As [Sathish Thangaraj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8656635/sathish-thangaraj) said, use `.append()` method:

---

```js
//http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/cpPsULBvKG?indent=2

$.getJSON("https://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/cpPsULBvKG?indent=2", function(data) {
  $.each(data, (i, el) => {
    $('#json_data').append(`<li>Value: ${el.value} | Key: ${el.key}</li>`);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="json_data">

</ul>
```

Comment: Nothing, I'm too used to using `.append()` as I don't need to `prepend` elements to the list :)